# ScalaTest: understanding the order of execution of tests

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am struggling to understand why my setup-teardown procedures are not working as I expect in ScalaTest. Basically, my test code looks as follows:

```
class UserManagerTest extends FlatSpec with ManagerBehaviors[User, UserDAO] {

  "An entity manager" should behave like allFindingManager(UserManager)

  "An entity manager" should behave like countingManager(UserManager)
}


trait ManagerBehaviors[T <: IEntity, D <: AbstractDAO[T]] {

this: FlatSpec =>

   private def withClearDB(entityManager: BasicManager[T, D], testFunction: () => Unit) = {
    try {
      clearDB(entityManager)
      testFunction()
    } finally {
      clearDB(entityManager)
    }
  }

  private def clearDB(manager: BasicManager[T, D]) = {
    manager.all match {
      case Some(entities) => for (entity <- entities) manager.remove(entity.getId)
    }
  }

  def allFindingManager(manager: BasicManager[T, D]) {
    withClearDB(manager,
      () => it should "properly return all elements in the database for the entity" in {

        // Add 10 entities to the database
        for (i <- 1 to 10) manager.persist(manager.defaultEntity)

        manager.all match {
          case Some(entities) => assert(entities.length == 10)
          case None => fail()
        }
      })
  }

  def countingManager(manager: BasicManager[T, D]) {
    withClearDB(manager,
      () => it should "properly count the number of entities managed" in {

        // Add 10 entities to the database
        for (i <- 1 to 10) manager.persist(manager.defaultEntity)

        assert(manager.count == 10)
      })
  }
}
```

What I expect is the following sequence:

1. clearDB
2. allFindingManager
3. clearDB
4. clearDB
5. countingManager
6. clearDB

When run in isolation, the tests work as expected - the DB is cleared upon start, and left empty when the test concluded.

However, when running the whole UserManagerTest class, for some reason it fails with the following:

```
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: 20 did not equal 10
```

The reason for this is that, somehow, the tests are being called right after each other WITHOUT the intermittent clearDB call. I am clueless as to why this is happening.

A possible clue to what is happening is found when using the debugger and placing a breakpoint inside the `finally` block: this block is indeed run twice as would be expected, but this happens BEFORE (!) the test methods are executed, which makes no sense at all:

1. clearDB
2. clearDB
3. clearDB
4. clearDB
5. allFindingManager
6. countingManager

Can anyone help me shed some light on this?

Comment: One thing I notice [in the doc section "calling loan-fixture methods"](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures) is that you wrap `withClearDb` outside the `should` clause but the doc uses the idiom `"something" should "do something" in withClearDb {`. Maybe you're getting caught in the gears of the DSL mechanism that way.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but I've ended up using BeforeAndAfter trait while dealing with similar issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change

```
def countingManager(manager: BasicManager[T, D]) {
  withClearDB(manager,
    () => it should "properly ..." in {

      // Add 10 entities to the database
      for (i <- 1 to 10) manager.persist(manager.defaultEntity)

      assert(manager.count == 10)
    })
}
```

to

```
def countingManager(manager: BasicManager[T, D]) {

  it should "properly ..." in withClearDB(manager,
    () => {
      // Add 10 entities to the database
      for (i <- 1 to 10) manager.persist(manager.defaultEntity)

      assert(manager.count == 10)
    }
  )

}
```

and likewise in the other function, then the order of execution will be as you expect.

Comment: Indeed, I was actually just going to come back and ask you to put your comment into an answer, since this solved the problem. I see you beat me to it, have an accept :) Thanks a lot.